# TViewport3D to export scenes to 3D files such as .obj

Tags: delphi, 3d

I have my own basic shapes in `TViewPort3D` and import a few 3D models via instances of `TModel3D` that is a child in `TViewPort3D`.

I would like to save the overall scene (with materials and lighting ideally) in an OBJ, DAE or any scene file that rendering software package can read.  Basically it means this final scene file contains all the 3D models in that scene.

How do I achieve this?  I don't see Save/Save As equivalents.

If `TViewPort3D` does nothing more than let a viewer view 3D contents, the use of Delphi as a 3D tool seems rather limited.